# Cannot get Intel MPX to work on supported kernel and compiler

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86-64, intel

I am a grad student and would like to check out how Intel Memory Protection eXtension (MPX) works. I am doing it on Ubuntu 20.04 system.

However, I think the MPX is not working based on the following two things:

1. The first one is Intel MPXcheck git repo: https://github.com/intel/mpxcheck
   There is a test/ directory which has 3 little c scripts.
   In either script, I keep getting `No MPX Support` in `stderr`.
2. The second one my little c script to perform `prctl` PR_MPX_ENABLE_MANAGEMENT

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int r = prctl(PR_MPX_ENABLE_MANAGEMENT,0,0,0,0);
  printf("%d\n", r);
  return 0;
}
```

This outputs `-1`, which I think it means that it is not supported.

platforms:
I am running some examples on machine with this CPU.
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i99900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html

My system is ubuntu 20.04, the kernel is 5.4 and I think the kernel before 5.6 still supports Intel MPX according to wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX).

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-155-generic
```

I am using the GCC-6.5 compiler. For all I know, versions between 5.x to 9.x should have support Intel MPX.

```
$ gcc-6 --version
gcc-6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I suspect that I need to make some configuration change to the kernel.
I have followed this link but I don't know what I am changing.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

I am working on it in a server that I SSH into.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a VM?  It might not pass through MPX.  And/or MPX might be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: You need a kernel compiled with CONFIG_X86_INTEL_MPX=y.  Documentation is here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.251/source/Documentation/x86/intel_mpx.rst

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the advice! I think I am not in a VM. I can get the name of the manufacturer via `dmidecode`. I am running on a server that I SSHed into. Is there any way to check the BIOS setting if I don't have the physical access?

Comment: @stark Thank you! I just compiled a kernel and enabled it via `make menuconfig`. The help page in the menu states that it's about the flag `CONFIG_X86_INTEL_MPX`. I enable it and `grub-mkconfig` the new kernel. However, I still get those little scripts work.

Comment: _Side note:_ gcc 6.x is a bit ancient as the newest is at least 12.x and maybe 13.x. I think Ubuntu 20 ships with a later gcc? I have fedora 29 (which is obsolete) and it has gcc 8.x